# Where to Put DispatchQueue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, spinner, grand-central-dispatch

I am a new developer.  I'm using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.2.

I'm trying to show a spinner while a photo is being saved.  I am simulating a slow connection on my iPhone in Developer Mode to test it.  Using the code below the spinner does not show up.  The view goes right to the end where the button shows and says the upload is complete (when it isn't).  I tried putting it all into a `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userinitiated).async` and then showing the button back on the main queue.  I also tried putting the `showSpinner` on a DispatchQueue.main and then `savePhoto` on a `.global(qos: .utility)`.  But I cleary don't understand the GCD processes.

Here's my code:

```
func savePhoto(image:UIImage) {

        // Add a spinner (from the Extensions)
        self.showSpinner(onView: self.view)

        PhotoService.savePhoto(image: image) { (pct) in

            // Can show the loading bar here.

        }

       // Stop the spinner
       self.removeSpinner()

       // Show the button.
       self.goToPhotosButtonLabel.alpha = 1
       self.doneLabel.alpha = 1
}
```

What types of DispatchQueues should I use and where should I put them?

Here is the savePhoto code:

```
static func savePhoto(image:UIImage, progressUpdate: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {

    // Get data representation of the image
    let photoData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality:0.1)

    guard photoData != nil else {
        print("Couldn't turn the image into data")
        return
    }

    // Get a storage reference
    let userid = LocalStorageService.loadCurrentUser()?.userId
    let filename = UUID().uuidString
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(String(describing: userid))/\(filename).jpg")

    // Upload the photo
    let uploadTask = ref.putData(photoData!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

        if error != nil {

            // An error during upload occurred
            print("There was an error during upload")
        }
        else {
            // Upload was successful, now create a database entry
            self.createPhotoDatabaseEntry(ref: ref, filename: filename)

        }
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in

        let percentage:Double = Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount /
        snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount) * 100.00

        progressUpdate(percentage)
    } 

}
```

Comment: Is your .savePhoto method asynchronous? And what does pct represent in the closure. The idea is if savePhoto is already asynchronous and the closure is called on success, you can stop the spinner and show the button inside the closure and hence may not need GCD in this particular case.

Comment: show `savePhoto` code ? where you save it locally / remotely ?

Comment: I presume .savePhoto is asynchronous because there is no GCD code in it.  I have added it above.

Comment: Put the `removeSpinner()` inside the completion callback of `savePhoto`

Comment: You are performing an upload task. Uploads are (or should be) asynchronous. Please read starting at http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/ and keep reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code that saves the photo is asynchronous , so your current code removes the spinner directly after it's added before the upload is complete

```
func savePhoto(image:UIImage) {

    // Add a spinner (from the Extensions)
    self.showSpinner(onView: self.view)

    PhotoService.savePhoto(image: image) { (pct) in

       //  remove spinner when progress is 100.0  = upload complete .
       if pct == 100.0 {
           // Stop the spinner
           self.removeSpinner() 
            // Show the button.
           self.goToPhotosButtonLabel.alpha = 1
           self.doneLabel.alpha = 1

        }
    } 
}
```

Here you don't have to use GCD as firebase upload runs in another background thread so it won't block the main thread

Comment: @rmaddy this depends on where Firebase progress notifies it's progress callback

Comment: No, the UI updates need to be on the main queue no matter what. Whether you need to use `DispatchQueue.main.async` depends on where Firebase calls the progress closure.

Comment: this is what i meant for e.x alamofire callback runs in main thread , UrlSession.shared tasks need `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: Sometimes the spinner doesn't stop.  Even when the photo is uploaded successfully.  I can jump to the feed and see that it is there, but when I go back to the add tab, the spinner is still going.

Comment: @TMLynch write directly above `progressUpdate(percentage)` do `print(Thread.isMainThread)` if you got `false` then wrap `DispatchQueue.main.async {    progressUpdate(percentage) }`

Comment: Tried twice.  Got true twice.  First time, button showed and all was good.  Second time, spinner kept going though photo was uploaded.

Comment: can you `print(pct)` it should be 100 finally ?

Comment: Put `print(pct)` above the `if pct == 100.0`.  Got 0.0 three times on an instance when the spinner wouldn't stop.  But the photo was uploaded.  Tried again and got 0.0 four times and then 100.0.

Comment: write below `self.createPhotoDatabaseEntry(ref: ref, filename: filename)` insert `progressUpdate(100.0)`

Comment: This seems to work.  I uploaded some smaller photos (on 3G setting) and it gave me 0.0 several times then 100.0.  Then I uploaded a very large panoramic photo and it gave me 0.0 about 12 times and then 100.0.  But why does it work?  Why wouldn't the percentages be accurate and why wouldn't the `uploadTask` send 100.0 when it was done every time?

Comment: Incidentally, I just did another upload and it worked, but I see it would not have worked if I did not have `progressUpdate(100.0)` in there.  The console shows `true` `0.0` and then `100.0` (without another `true`) which means it did not come back to the closure with 100.0 from the `uploadTask` observer.  Strange.